# Automapper raised Error mapping types on upgrade to 11.0.0 (List to Dictionary)

Tags: automapper

I have a problem on map of property with type List to Dictionary.
this code was success on Automapper 10.1.1 and error raised after upgrade to 11.0.0.

```cs
CreateMap<ProcessActorEntity, ProcessActorViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProcessRoles.ToDictionary(x => x.Role.Id, x => x.Role.Title)));
```

Roles is a List of role entity.

ProcessRoles a is Dictionary.

It's work on AutoMapper V10.1.1, and Not work on V11.0.0

> Error mapping types ... Destination Member: Roles

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail. But you need a type converter here, not a value resolver. So fixing your mapping is best.

Comment: @mRizvandi We also are having HUGE! problems with upgrading from 10 to 11. All sorts of errors are appearing when they worked fine on 10. How can they create an upgrasde that breaks every code. They don't even tell you what the breaking changes are. I think this issue is the first of your problems. We are abandoning using Automapper as advised by other experts that eventually one has to bin it so might as well do it now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error on the run-time:

In Automapper V10.1.1, no error raised, if Role be null
But in Version V11+, Automapper raised error, is Role is null.

Role is null and It's our fault. but Automapper has different approach in versions.

Role is null and Automapper can not access the Id and Title members.